# Recursion in OCL

Tags: uml, ocl

Let suppose I have this class diagram in UML:

[image: recursion in OCL]

How can I do, in OCL, to specify that an instance of A is not included in list_of_As recursively ? In other words, an instance of A may not be included in A.list_of_As and not be included in all list_of_As of all instances of A in A.list_of_As etc... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [transitive closure operator, closure()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.ocl.doc/help/ProgrammersGuide.html), to get a list of A. Then, simply check for the non-existence of the element you don't want to see in that list.